# How to check what header is passed in the request configuration in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

How can I find out whether the right header has been passed to my request or not.

This is my header

```
<http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    Authorization : vars.authorizationToken
}]]]></http:headers>
```

My request is failing again and again as right token is not passed.

**UPDATE:**

After enabling wire-logging.I observed that my Header's case was not preserved. I enabled the case and it started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wire logging to see the actual HTTP message being sent. See this [guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-troubleshooting#wire-logging) for details.

Comment: I think it is passing my token with double quotes : Authorization: "token" instead of passing it as Authorization: token . How do I remove double quotes ??

Comment: You'd have to check how that variable is being set, perhaps the quotes are there already.

Comment: The variable is set when token is received by HTTP Listener. Now, how do I remove double quotes ?

Comment: That's a different question than the original one. You should ask a new one about the quotes.

Comment: @afelisatti So in the logs, I found that the Authorization in my header was converted to authorization. I think this is the reason behind the request failure

Comment: That's expected behavior.

Comment: HTTP headers are case insensitive, it shouldn't matter what case they are in. If that is indeed the problem then you are dealing with a non RFC compliant server. I suggest trying with a different client , like postman or curl, sending the header in lower case to validate whether that is indeed the issue. For the quotes thing, it may be the format you are storing that variable in when extracting it from wherever it's coming, I'd make sure it's `application/java`.

Comment: @afelisatti You were right , I was dealing with a non RFC compliant server. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: If I recall correctly there's a "preserveHeadersCase" option in the HTTP components  to deal with kind of servers.